# Sql Server Replication increase values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, replication

I have a mission, to make some Replication from one database to another.
I have one database TestDB with table:

```
Students ([RollNo] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
          [Name] [varchar](20) NULL,
          [Class] [int] NULL,
          [House] [varchar](10) NULL )
```

And when I make replication it must replicate this table to dbo.SampleDB, but it must increase value "+2" in "Class" column... May be I have to use stored procedure, but how can I write it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ProcTest

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    select * into SampleDB..Students
    from TestDB..Students
    update SampleDB..Students set Class= Class+2
    END
```

Comment: It does not recognize "TestDB.dbo.Students"

Comment: You could use Import and Export Data (64 or 32 bit) also if you don't want to write sql.

Comment: no...doesn`t work...but don`t worry ...thank for all of procedures :)

Comment: No,there is no errors...its just not working...I make replication and create this procedure ,but when I insert new values it doesn`t increase 2 to Class column in SampleDB

Comment: In my code, you're copying all the columns and their values (each row) into a table Students in SampleDB. It also updates this table so the values in the column Class are increased by 2. Isn't that what you want ?

Comment: NEW values you insert into Students in SampleDB manually are not gonna get increased by +2 only the values you're taking from Students in TestDB.